# ¿Como hacer un ciclo for en el template de Flask en un rango cuyo valor lo traigo desde el codigo en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Logre hacer un ciclo for en el template en Flask para un rango definido, pero lo que necesito es que el numero sobre el cual hago el rango venga del código de Python. Pongo el código que logre que funcione y lo que intenté:

HTML:

```
{% for fila in range(3) %}
    {% for columna in range(3) %}
        <a href= {{ url_for('numero', fila=fila ,columna=columna) }}><boton>{{fila}}{{columna}}</boton></a>

        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

PYTHON:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def inicio():

    return render_template("1.html")

@app.route("/<fila>/<columna>")
def numero(fila=None, columna=None):

    fil = fila
    col = columna
    return (str(fil)+"-"+str(col))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que en vez de poner in range(3) lograr que el numero del rango provenga de una variable de python.
Pongo lo que estuve intentando:

HTML:

```
{% for fila in range({{ rango }}) %}
    {% for columna in range({{ rango }}) %}
        <a href= {{ url_for('numero', fila=fila,columna=columna) }}><boton>{{fila}}{{columna}}</boton></a>

        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

PYTHON:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def inicio():
    rango = 3
    return render_template("1.html", rango=rango)

@app.route("/<fila>/<columna>")
def numero(fila=None, columna=None):

    fil = fila
    col = columna
    return (str(fil)+"-"+str(col))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Creo que es tan simple como `{% for fila in range(rango) %}`

Comment: Es cierto, funciona perfecto! No tengo muy en claro aun cuando llamar a las variables con o sin corchetes. Muchas gracias

Comment: Básicamente, dentro de un trozo delimitado por `{% ... %}` estás metiendo código jinja (similar a python, pero no igual). En él las variables que hayas pasado al template están accesibles. Fuera de un trozo `{% ... %}` todo se considera texto sin más y no se toca, salvo que aparezca algo entre `{{ }}` y entonces se interpreta como una expresión jinja, que normalmente será el nombre de una variable y se sustituirá por el valor de la misma.